# Bing Maps can't find 10 Downing Street

Tags: bing-maps, geocoding

I have an English OS, Firefox locale is English. I happen to physically be in Japan.
Bing Maps can't find `10 Downing Street, London`:

[image: Bing Maps]

---

It can find Japanese addresses, though.

**QUESTION:** Is there a way to make Bing Maps understand addresses of all countries, not just the country I happen to be in right now?

- I never asked Bing to use Japanese. I just happen to be in Japan.
- I don't have a Bing account. The [setting](https://www.bing.com/account/general) (default) appear to be English:

[image] [image]

Comment: Are you running Japanese OS or English OS? And you are in Japan? Since the site and map are returned in Japanese, I could only assume Bing knows something its not telling. And as you are typing the address, do you see any search hints? I saw many, so where they are might help localize this. Anyway, in the US finding the London address works OK.

Comment: @nic Try using [Bing Maps (Ditu)](http://cn.bing.com/ditu/). It worked for me and displayed as English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also have English OS, Firefox using English locale, and I am in the US.

So to force me to use Japanese map service, I went to www.bing.co.jp (same as I do for Google when I explicitly want Japanese results), the select **Maps** from the top menu. Since you are in Japan, Bing might be sending you there by default.

Then I entered "10 Downing Street, London" as you did. Well, it could not find it.

[image]

What I finally figured out is that you have to enter the search location in katakana as it is shown on the map. Not there, no dice.

[image]

In UK and US maps, zooming in there are cities in alpha text, but search could not find them. I think if you can find "10 Downing Street" by going there on the map manually you will see what you can search for (as long as it is in katakana). Kind of backwards though.

EDIT - Additional Information:

Based on OP's feedback, he could go to a national Bing site you would expect to be in English (in this case www.bing.co.uk was tried), and the maps were in English again. Then (again from Japan) maps on www.bing.com also were in English, probably due to a cookie being set.

Comment: Also, if you do the same on Google Maps, you will see that locations are double-labeled (alpha and katakana), so this problem won't occur for most locations. And yes, Google Maps could find "10 Downing St.")..

Comment: Also, maybe you can try www.bing.co.uk and check Maps there.

Comment: I went to http://www.bing.co.uk and clicked "Maps". It seems to have set up some kind of cookie, because now ALL Bing maps pages show up in English, whatever URL I use! Could you please add this tip at the top of your answer? Thanks for the investigation! :-)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback; I added the additional information to my answer.  Similar results might depend on where one is.